# Duplicate Nodes with different input

Tags: xslt-1.0

Background info.  I'm writing an XSL file to take an XML sent to the server by an analytical instrument and translate that file into an XML file accepted by our LIMS system.

Here is a Simple XML file coming from the instrument:

```
<dataRoot>
<dataRow>
<a0>2020-05-29 10:48:09 UTC-4</a0>
<a1>MSA - Conc.(Bench)</a1>
<a2>WHC202005270038</a2>
<a3>00251832</a3>
<a4>1.15966</a4>
<a5>MSA</a5>
<a6>101.067</a6>
</dataRow>
</dataRoot>
```

Here is what I have so far for the XSL File:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"/>

<xsl:template match="/dataRoot">

<INBOUND>
    <xsl:call-template name="A"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="A" />
</INBOUND>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/dataRow" name="A">
    <xsl:for-each select="dataRow">
            <xsl:variable name="sSampleID" select="normalize-space(a2)" />
            <xsl:variable name="sSubmitter">AutoT_EQ00004</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="sEnteredBy">EQ00004</xsl:variable>
            <!-- Use a variable for OWNER, so that only one spot needs changing if a different value is desired -->
            <xsl:variable name="sOwner">WHC</xsl:variable>                          
                <xsl:variable name="sParameter" select="normalize-space(a5)" />                 
                <xsl:variable name="sParamName"> <!-- Parameter names mapping for import to LIMS-->
                <xsl:call-template name="ConvertPaName">
                    <xsl:with-param name="sPaName" select="$sParameter" />
                </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>                                 
                <xsl:variable name="sResult" select="normalize-space(a6)" />
                <xsl:for-each select="$sParamName">

                                <INBOX_SAMPLE>
                                    <EVENT>1</EVENT>
                                    <SAMPLE_ID><xsl:value-of select="$sSampleID"/></SAMPLE_ID>
                                    <SUBMITTER><xsl:value-of select="$sSubmitter" /></SUBMITTER>
                                    <ENTERED_BY><xsl:value-of select="$sEnteredBy" /></ENTERED_BY>
                                    <OWNER><xsl:value-of select="$sOwner" /></OWNER>
                                    <PARAMETER_NAME><xsl:value-of select="$sParamName"/></PARAMETER_NAME>
                                    <SRESULT><xsl:value-of select="$sResult"/></SRESULT>        
                                </INBOX_SAMPLE>
                </xsl:for-each>             
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Convert PaNames as needed, and skip processing certain values that are not actual Parameters (ie: 'Application') -->
<xsl:template name="ConvertPaName">
    <xsl:param name="sPaName" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$sPaName='MSA'">MSA - Conc.(Bench)</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$sPaName='MSA'">Free MSA</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>Halt_Import</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the output of current translation:

```
<INBOUND>
   <INBOX_SAMPLE>
      <EVENT>1</EVENT>
      <SAMPLE_ID>WHC202005270038</SAMPLE_ID>
      <SUBMITTER>AutoT_EQ00004</SUBMITTER>
      <ENTERED_BY>EQ00004</ENTERED_BY>
      <OWNER>WHC</OWNER>
      <PARAMETER_NAME>MSA - Conc.(Bench)</PARAMETER_NAME>
      <SRESULT>101.067</SRESULT>
   </INBOX_SAMPLE>
</INBOUND>
```

What I need to do is to duplicate this node for both parameter names:

```
<xsl:when test="$sPaName='MSA'">MSA - Conc.(Bench)</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$sPaName='MSA'">Free MSA</xsl:when>
```

So that my output becomes:

```
<INBOUND>
   <INBOX_SAMPLE>
      <EVENT>1</EVENT>
      <SAMPLE_ID>WHC202005270038</SAMPLE_ID>
      <SUBMITTER>AutoT_EQ00004</SUBMITTER>
      <ENTERED_BY>EQ00004</ENTERED_BY>
      <OWNER>WHC</OWNER>
      <PARAMETER_NAME>MSA - Conc.(Bench)</PARAMETER_NAME>
      <SRESULT>101.067</SRESULT>
   </INBOX_SAMPLE>
   <INBOX_SAMPLE>
      <EVENT>1</EVENT>
      <SAMPLE_ID>WHC202005270038</SAMPLE_ID>
      <SUBMITTER>AutoT_EQ00004</SUBMITTER>
      <ENTERED_BY>EQ00004</ENTERED_BY>
      <OWNER>WHC</OWNER>
      <PARAMETER_NAME>Free MSA</PARAMETER_NAME>
      <SRESULT>101.067</SRESULT>
   </INBOX_SAMPLE>
</INBOUND>
```

This is because instrument sends one parameter name like "MSA" but in our LIMS we have it under either "Free MSA" or "MSA - Conc.(Bench)" and I need to be able to provide the result for both possible parameter names and LIMS will insert the one that it find a match for.

Thank you so much in advanced :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add parm elements to template.

```
<xsl:template name="ConvertPaName">
    <xsl:param name="sPaName" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$sPaName='MSA'">
          <parm>MSA - Conc.(Bench)</parm>
          <parm>Free MSA</parm>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <parm>Halt_Import</parm>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Call your template

```
<xsl:variable name="sParamName"> 
  <xsl:call-template name="ConvertPaName">
    <xsl:with-param name="sPaName" select="$sParameter" />
   </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Convert to node set:  (However you do it.  You currently don't have the msxml namespace set up.)

```
<xsl:variable name="sParamNameList" select="msxml:node-set($sParamName)">
```

Then use the parm list in your for-each loop.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$sParamNameList/parm">
```